# How to rotate a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm developing a board game and would like to know how i can use css or JavaScript to dynamically rotate a div so that each player can play from bottom up.

**Player One**

[image]

---

**Player Two**

[image]

Comment: Your board isn't flipped, it's rotated 180 degrees. You should be implementing logic to let the player start as either color, not hacking it up with CSS.

Comment: The board is rotated 180 degrees in the image above versus a mirror image which is what meagar is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From earlier stackoverflow post:

[Cross-browser way to flip html/image via Javascript/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309055/cross-browser-way-to-flip-image-via-javascript-css)

```
.flip-vertical {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    filter: flipv; /*IE*/
}
```

Comment: This works but dragging and dropping is no longer working - am using jQuery UI.

Comment: Try removing the image class on mouse down, hiding the original image, dragging a placeholder image and then reattaching upon release. That way jQuery behaviour will remain unaffected during the dragging and dropping.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate the image 180 degrees and then expect dragging and dropping to work, you need to be a little less lazy and just code the thing from each user's perspective IMO.

Comment: Didn't want to re-invent the wheel - if there's no easier way then that would be my last option.