# Can't figure out how to make the nivo slider arrow face the correct way

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried everything to make the previous arrow face the correct way and just can't get it. If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate the help. Also, while I'm asking a question already, how do you get the numbers (for which slide your on) to show up on the bottom of the images instead of under the slider?

Here is a link to a screen cap of the image:  http://postimg.org/image/xsnhdk9o9/

Below is my css code.

```
.nivo-directionNav a 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:url(../images/blue_arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    display:block
}

.nivo-prevNav 
{
    left:15px;
}

.nivo-nextNav 
{
    right:15px;
    background-position:-60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this class to the image you want to flip.

```
.flip-horizontal {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
    filter: fliph; /*IE*/
}
```

From... [Cross-browser way to flip html/image via Javascript/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309055/cross-browser-way-to-flip-html-image-via-javascript-css/1309275#1309275)

Comment: Still didn't flip. I have no idea what is going on. I have been stuck trying to figure this out for an hour now and nothing seems to work. I'm almost ready to just go with no arrows. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @WastelandENT I dont know if its possible to do all with CSS. Try reversing the original image in paint. Look here http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070713082453AAPXp2S. Then just make the left arrow have that image

Comment: You're a lifesaver! after everything I tried, I can't believe it never popped into my mind to just flip the image in PS -_-

Comment: @WastelandENT Yeaht thats what I was trying to do in the CSS but its often way easier to just have two images